# Is there a way to send multiple emails to multiple users from google sheets while looping through a list of messages?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

Hey this is my first question on StackOverflow.
I've been struggling with this code for two days and tried to move the loops up and down but nothing happened. The code doesn't show any error but i don't get a mail.
What I'm trying to do is to send multiple messages (sheet: buysignals) to multiple users (sheet: Sheet1). It should appear that everyone gets each email as the only receiver. f.ex. you get a new mail if there is a text in the Buysignals sheet.
Anyone here who can help me how to fix it?

```
function sendBuySignal() {
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Buysignals");
const dataRange = sheet.getRange("A2:R17");
const data = dataRange.getValues();

  
  data.forEach(function (rowData) {
    const ticker = rowData[0];
    
    // Stock info
    const kurtosis = rowData[1];
    const sigma = rowData[2];
    const mCap = rowData[17];
    const std = rowData[4];
    const timeStamp = rowData[6];
    const buyPrice = rowData[8];
    const buyIndicator = rowData[16];
    
    
    // Send Signal Mail
    if (buyIndicator > 0) {
      const greeting = 'The stock ' + ticker + ',\n'
      const buyMessage = 'Is at ' + timeStamp + ' in the buy zone at ' + buyPrice + '. With a kurtosis of ' + kurtosis + ', sigma ' + sigma + ', mcap in bill ' + mCap + '.';
      const greatJobMessage = 'Hurry up! Go buy it :)';
      
      const message = [greeting, buyMessage, greatJobMessage].join('\n');
      const subject = 'Test: New Buy ' + ticker;
      
      // Fetch the email address
      const emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
      const n=emailRange.getLastRow();
      for (var i = 2; i > n+1 ; i++ ) {
        const emailAddress = emailRange.getRange(i,1).getValue();   
      }
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    }
      return

      })

}
```

Comment: Do you want to send each data row from `BuySignals` to the email recipient specified in the same row of `Sheet1`?

Comment: @ziganotschka Each data row from `BuySignals` to every single recipient in `Sheet1`.  The code works if I put one recipient are sell to all of them in one single mail. What I want to do is that nobody sees who gets the same mail. Tried with BCC but you still see who gets one email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The issue is related to looping

1. The syntax `for (var i = 2; i > n+1 ; i++ ) {` cannot work

- Assuming that the last row is bigger than the start row (that is bigger than 2) the condition `i > n+1` will never be fulfilled, so you will not enter the loop - instead you should specify `i < n`
- It is `n` and not `n+1` because you start with the second row instead of the first (`i = 2`)

2. `MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);` is located outside of the `for` loop

- This means that in each loop the function overwrites the `emailAddress` and after exiting the loop you will send a single email - to the last saved email address
- This issue can be solved by inserting `MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);` inside the `for` loop

**Sample:**

```js
function sendBuySignal() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Buysignals");
  const dataRange = sheet.getRange("A2:R17");
  const data = dataRange.getValues();
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var n = sheet1.getLastRow();
  const emails = sheet1.getRange("A2:A" + n).getValues();
  
  data.forEach(function (rowData) {
    const ticker = rowData[0];
    
    // Stock info
    const kurtosis = rowData[1];
    const sigma = rowData[2];
    const mCap = rowData[17];
    const std = rowData[4];
    const timeStamp = rowData[6];
    const buyPrice = rowData[8];
    const buyIndicator = rowData[16];
    
    // Send Signal Mail
    if (buyIndicator > 0) {
      Logger.log("buyIndicator > 0");
      const greeting = 'The stock ' + ticker + ',\n'
      const buyMessage = 'Is at ' + timeStamp + ' in the buy zone at ' + buyPrice + '. With a kurtosis of ' + kurtosis + ', sigma ' + sigma + ', mcap in bill ' + mCap + '.';
      const greatJobMessage = 'Hurry up! Go buy it :)';
      
      const message = [greeting, buyMessage, greatJobMessage].join('\n');
      const subject = 'Test: New Buy ' + ticker;
      
      // Fetch the email address
      for (var i = 0; i < emails.length ; i++ ) {
        var emailAddress = emails[i][0];
        Logger.log("email: " + emailAddress);  
        MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      }        
    }       
  })  
}
```

Note that for this sample I allowed myself to retrieve all emails before entering the loop. This is [more efficient](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#minimize_calls_to_other_services) than multiple calls of `getRange()` within each loop iteration.

Comment: Awesome! It worked. Stupid beginner question: Do I need the Logger.log in the final script?